# How to make the button click works after ajax is executed in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, click

I can not get the button to be clicked, however it is working rarely
I tried waits such as:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(ViewBtn)).Click();
```

it is not even waiting, it goes immediately to the next line of code which means that the button is clickable.

I also tried to click it using Javascript but it is not working also:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", ViewBtn);
```

Whatever I try to use to click the button, it does not work and it does not cause any exceptions to be thrown.

This button exists in a table, in every row, there is a column that contains anchor text, so I am clicking the td, originally it is clickable but when I filter the table using a search condition the button stops working, (clicking manually still works)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by dealing with the anchor text instead of clicking the td, it works now, I find it strange because it works before the filtering process and stops after